# Angular autocomplete on select get all object of selected value

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, angular-material2

I have an autocomplete component.

I passe an array of object.

I would like that when I select an option I get all item informations (`option`) not just the field value  (`option.name`)

```
<form class="example-form">
    <mat-form-field class="example-full-width">
        <input type="text" placeholder="Pick one" aria-label="Number" matInput [formControl]="myControl"
            [matAutocomplete]="auto">
        <mat-autocomplete #auto="matAutocomplete" (optionSelected)='selectOption($event.option)'>
            <mat-option *ngFor="let option of filteredOptions | async" [value]="option.name">
                {{option.name}}
            </mat-option>
        </mat-autocomplete>
    </mat-form-field>
    <router-outlet></router-outlet>
</form>
```

Component ts

```
export class SearchLeagueComponent implements OnInit {
  constructor(private searchLeagueService: SearchLeagueService) { }
  myControl = new FormControl();
  options: ILeague[] = [
    {
      _id: '',
      teams: [],
      name: '',
      sport: ''
    }
  ];
  filteredOptions: Observable<ILeague[]> | undefined

  ngOnInit() {
    this.searchLeagueService.getLeaguesList().toPromise().then(data => this.options = data)
    this.filteredOptions = this.myControl.valueChanges
      .pipe(
        //startWith(''),
        map((value: string) => this._filter(value))
      );
  }
  selectOption(val: string) {
    console.log(val)
  }
  private _filter(value: string): ILeague[] {
    const filterValue = value.toLowerCase();
    return this.options.filter(option => option.name.toLowerCase().includes(filterValue));
  }
}
```

Actually I'm  using `(optionSelected)` but it only return selected value.

I should get also the id.

Comment: meybe you should just pass the ($event) just like  `(optionSelected)="onItemSelect($event)"`

Comment: It will send an `$event` but the value will contain same thing

Answer (score 3):

You should pass the **($event)** to selectOption().

```html
<form class="example-form">
    <mat-form-field class="example-full-width">
        <input type="text" placeholder="Pick one" aria-label="Number" matInput [formControl]="myControl"
            [matAutocomplete]="auto">
        <mat-autocomplete #auto="matAutocomplete" (optionSelected)='selectOption($event)'>
            <mat-option *ngFor="let option of filteredOptions | async" [value]="option.name">
                {{option.name}}
            </mat-option>
        </mat-autocomplete>
    </mat-form-field>
    <router-outlet></router-outlet>
</form>
```

then get your object in selectOption() like this

```js
import { MatAutocompleteSelectedEvent } from '@angular/material/autocomplete';


  selectOption(e: MatAutocompleteSelectedEvent) {
     const item: **YOUR INTERFACE** = e.option.value;
     console.log(item);
  }
```

[image]

Comment: That's what I'm doing, but I'm getting `option.name` not `option`, when I edit mat-option `[value]` to `option` I get all object in `$event.option.value` but it render `[object object]` in input UI

Comment: have you `[value]="option.name` in your code example or `[value]="option`

Comment: Yes but the filter function will throw an error because of ‘.toLowerCase()‘ , I set a condition to verify the type of the parameter , if string use toLowerCase , if not (type is ILeague ) parse param ( value.name) . But I don't think it's the sexiest way .

Answer (score 3):

Try to use itemDispalayFn function to display options

```html
    <mat-form-field class="example-full-width">
        <input type="text" placeholder="Pick one" aria-label="Number" matInput [formControl]="myControl"
            [matAutocomplete]="auto">
        <mat-autocomplete #auto="matAutocomplete" (optionSelected)='selectOption($event)'
            [displayWith]="itemDisplayFn">
            <mat-option *ngFor="let option of filteredOptions | async" 
            [value]="option.name">
                {{option.name}}
            </mat-option>
        </mat-autocomplete>
```

```js
  itemDisplayFn(item: YOUR INTERFACE) {
        return item? item.name: '';
    }
```

Comment: that does help for display but not for selecting the value, I still get a string instead of the object of type `ILeague`

Comment: You need to change [value]="option.name" to [value]="option" then it will display the value returned in itemDisplayFn and the value of the input will be the whole object.

Answer (score 0):

I think your issue is very relate to my current development issue. which I have solve using below ways:

### Html

```
<mat-autocomplete #auto="matAutocomplete" (optionSelected)='selectOption($event.option,$event.option._element.nativeElement.OptionValue)'>
    <mat-option [OptionValue]="option" *ngFor="let option of filteredOptions | async" [value]="option.name">
        {{option.name}}
    </mat-option>
</mat-autocomplete>
```

### .ts File

```
selectOption(val: string,option:any) {
  console.log(val);
  console.log("option : ",option);
}
```

Hope it help you.

> Here in this example I have fill current option value inside custom
> attribute(OptionValue). Once event fire then that attribute value pass
> as an argument of `'selectOption()'` function.